# Updating one table with a date I just derived from a subquery in tsql

Tags: t-sql

I don't understand why this t-sql query doesn't work.

What is it about MSSQL (or just SQL) in general, that won't allow me to update one table with a date I just derived from a subquery?

```
UPDATE table1
SET someOldDate = innertable.derivedDate
WHERE
uniqueId in 

(SELECT CAST(str(table2.VisitMo)+"/"+str(table2.Visitday)+"/"+ str(table2.Visityr) as datetime) as derivedDate
    ,uniqueId
 FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 
 ON t1.uniqueId = t2.uniqueId
 WHERE CAST(str(t2.VisitMo)+"/"+str(t2.visitday)+"/"+ str(t2.visityr))  != t2.someOldDate) as innertable
```

I don't mind that the query doesn't work, but it drives me nuts that I don't get why it doesn't work. 
Any philosophical advice gladly taken.

Answer (score 0):

try with this :

```
Update table1
SET table1.someOldDate =
CAST(str(table2.VisitMo)+"/"+str(table2.Visitday)+"/"+ str(table2.Visityr) as datetime)
From table1
inner join table2 On table1.uniqueId = table2.uniqueId.
where CAST(str(table2.VisitMo)+'/'+str(table2.visitday)+'/'+ str(table2.visityr))  != table2.someOldDate
```

Answer (score 0):

In an instance where you're using

```
WHERE X IN (SUBQUERY)
```

SQL's process is to:

1. Run the subquery to produce a list of values
2. Compare that list of values against the values in column X
3. Based on the truth value of that comparison, include or exclude each row for select/insert/update.

At no point in this process is any information passed out about *which* entry or entries in the list matched to the value in column X. This is what makes IN useful - SQL minimizes the amount of work it does by saying 'this works if X is in this list at least once'.

If you want to do something like an 'update table A based on a common link to B', you might look at using JOINs in your UPDATE. [Pinal Dave is a pretty good resource.](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/04/30/sql-server-update-from-select-statement-using-join-in-update-statement-multiple-tables-in-update-statement/)

Answer (score 0):

You have an `IN` clause that appears to be checking if the `uniqueId` is in a list of possible values. However: your subquery is returning **two** columns.....

So basically, you have

```
UPDATE table1
SET someOldDate = innertable.derivedDate
WHERE uniqueId IN (SELECT derivedDate, uniqueId
                   FROM table1 t1 .....)
```

You can't do this - if you have an `IN` clause, the subquery that returns the possible values **must** return just a list of that **one column** that you want to check against!

`uniqueId` cannot be checked against a list of `(derivedDate, uniqueId)` - it must be checked against a list of just `(uniqueId)` only ....